# GSP variables set in layout not visible in pages

Tags: grails, gsp

I have some GSP variables set in the "main" layout file of my Grails application (included below). The values of these variables don't appear to be accessible in the GSP pages that are rendered by the sitemesh. Also, they are not visible in any templates that are rendered by the  tag. I have tried setting the scope="request" (see code) below, but that doesn't appear to make any difference. I'm clearly not understanding the scoping rules for GSP variables.

Can anyone clarify how GSP variables are scoped and make a recommendation on how I can communicate them from the layout all the way down to templates (if I can at all).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%-- <html lang="${org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request).toString().replace('_', '-')}"> --%>
<html lang="${session.'org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE'}">

<head>
    <title><g:layoutTitle default="${meta(name:'app.name')}" /></title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"       content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description"    content="">
    <meta name="author"         content="">

    <asset:javascript src="bootstrap.js" />
    <theme:load />
    <asset:javascript src="application.js" />
    <asset:stylesheet src="application.css" />
    <asset:link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

    <g:layoutHead />

    <%-- Defineform body layout column dimensions. These values are used by Bootstrap based forms to 
         layout using configured column widths and offsets. --%>
    <g:set var="labelWidth" value="${grailsApplication.config.ark.layout.labelWidth ?: 'col-sm-3'}" scope="request" />         
    <g:set var="controlWidth" value="${grailsApplication.config.ark.layout.controlWidth ?: 'col-sm-4'}" scope="request" />
    <g:set var="controlOffset" value="${grailsApplication.config.ark.layout.controlWidth ?: 'col-sm-offset-3'}" scope="request" />

    <%-- For Javascript see end of body --%>
</head>

<body>
    <g:render plugin="arkUi" template="/layouts/menu/navbar"/>
    <g:render plugin="arkUi" template="/layouts/content"/>
    <g:render plugin="arkUi" template="/layouts/footer"/>

    <!-- Include deferred Javascript files and other resources -->
    <asset:deferredScripts/>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is this an app or a plugin?  If the former, why not just put the default values into `Config.groovy`?

Comment: It is an application that consumes a large number of plugins, many of which provide visual components. The application defines the basic layout metrics in the form of bootstrap grid classes which we would like our plugin provided components to be able to pick up. Easy enough -- we can always pick up the config value and just use it. We would also like to be able to override this on a page basis, if we are using modal dialog (for example). It seems reasonable that we could set a top level variable and then override at the page level. But ... no joy. Based on experiments, I think I'm screwed.

Comment: Placing a variable in the request scope of a page appears to do nothing. It is not visible in any template rendered with <g:render> for example. I'm not sure what the benefit is to the scoping options.

Comment: I think your problem is that it's the other way around - the page is parsed first, then the layout, so the layout can see things you set in the page but not vice-versa.

Comment: AH! You're right of course. I tend not to think of it that way, because the layout includes the header content and footer pieces, but that is exactly the issue. When the sitemesh does it's thing the scope hasn't been set yet. Crap. Thanks for that.

Comment: If you recast this as an answer, I'll mark it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that Grails first parses the target GSP page to (among other things) determine which layout to use, *then* parses the layout GSP and combines them.  So the layout can see variables you set in the page but not vice-versa.